# JQuery Reload div data Only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery and facing an issue while refreshing div using following script

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        $("#dbq").load("dbqtest.php");
      }, 10000); //Delay here = 10 sec
    }); 
</script>
```

```html
<?php
echo '<section class="col-lg-6" id="dbq">';
echo '<p>My Section </p>';
echo '</section>';
?>
```

The section i am trying to refresh is declared as below

The problem i am facing is that whenever the page loads for the first time, table from "dbqtest.php" is not visible for 1st 10 seconds. and My section stays there even after loading data from "dbqtest.php"

Comment: Could you add "<" at the end of the code? I can't see the result because of error.
I mean </script>

Comment: setInterval is not for delay. that will run your script every 10 seconds

Comment: @Saf i am not trying to add delay. I just want section to reload after 10 seconds without reloading page.

Comment: Use setTimeout instead

Comment: first you need to check what does dbqtest.php return

Answer (score 0):

You need a wrapper for reloading `section`. Somthing like this must work:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(
 function() {
  setInterval(function() {
   $("#dbq-wrapper").load("dbqtest.php");
  }, 10000); //Delay here = 10 sec
 });
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="dbq-wrapper">
 <section class="col-lg-6" id="dbq">
  <p>My Section </p>
 </section>
</div>
```

Hoever you can use `div` inside `section` and reload data to that and use `section` as parent, anyway you need wrapper.

---

As you want to the first time load without delay, the solution is somthing like this:

```
< script >
    function dbqLoader {
        $("#dbq").load("dbqtest.php");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
            dbqLoader(); // for first time.
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {dbqLoader();}, 10000); // Loop with Delay
            });  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this already, table won't load for first 10 seconds

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstood your question, the new code must solve your problem. however it's better to use wrapper too.

Comment: Isn't it logical that your code doesn't load for the first 10 seconds. When your script loads then it waits for 10 seconds and executes the .load() function and repeats every 10 seconds. Check this example on W3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval - when you click on the button for the first time, you have to wait 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dbq").load("dbqtest.php");
        setInterval(function() {
               $("#dbq").load("dbqtest.php");
        }, 10000); 
    });
</script>
```

It's very similar to M.Abooali's answer but I've fixed some issues and minimised it.